# H1 not being controlled by my CSS Stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out why my H1 on my html page isn't styling in accordance with my stylesheet coding.  Everything else appears to be working.  My website files are here: [Website Files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxpAw7Kru629aTlNRDBIb0pZQkk/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] in your question. Not a link to a zip file in Google Drive.

Answer (score 3):

None of your styles are taking effect because you included HTML tags in your CSS file: `<style type="text/css">` and `</style>`.

Those tags are only used in HTML - you don't need them in an external .css file.